# How can I use and extract kerning pairs from from GPOS table in Opentype fonts to correctly show glyphs as Path2D in Java?

Tags: java, opentype, kerning

This question is related to a few questions that have been asked long time ago. I saw comments that **Opentype** fonts were not supported in Java, but this was 11 years ago. Nowadays they are. The only problem is that **kerning pairs** are only given in the **GPOS** table. I have seen that they are there but it is hard to make sure the code is correct.

I am currently dumping the **GPOS** table trying to follow the pointers until the kerning pairs.

The code so far is below, where **GPOS** table has been previously copied to the array `gpos`. The function to dump the table is `dumpGPOS()`. I need help to determine if what I am doing is correct and how to code the **TODO** parts:

```
byte[] gpos;

char[] hexasc( char[] hex, byte num ) {
    int up = num >> 4;
    int down = num & 15;
    hex[0] = (char) ((up < 10)? '0' + up : 'A' + up - 10);
    hex[1] = (char) ((down < 10)? '0' + down : 'A' + down - 10);
    return hex;
}

char[] hex = { '0', '0' };
void printHex(byte b) {
    hexasc(hex, b);
    System.out.print(hex[0]);
    System.out.print(hex[1]);
}

void dumpGPOS() {
    int i, j;
    System.out.println("GPOS header");
    System.out.print("Version:        ");
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) printHex(gpos[i]);
    System.out.println("    (" + (gpos[0] << 8 | gpos[1]) + "." + (gpos[2] << 8 | gpos[3]) + ")" );
    j = i;
    System.out.print("TheScriptList:        ");
    for ( i = 4; i < 6; i++ ) printHex(gpos[i]);
    System.out.println("        (" + (gpos[j] << 8 | gpos[j+1]) + ")" );
    j = i;
    System.out.print("TheFeatureList:        ");
    for ( i = 6; i < 8; i++ ) printHex(gpos[i]);
    System.out.println("        (" + (gpos[j] << 8 | gpos[j+1]) + ")" );
    j = i;
    System.out.print("TheLookupList:        ");
    for ( i = 8; i < 10; i++ ) printHex(gpos[i]);
    int lookup = (gpos[j] << 8 | gpos[j+1]);
    System.out.println("        (" + lookup + ")" );
    j = i;

    System.out.println("Lookup List Table");
    System.out.print("lookupCount:        ");
    for ( i = lookup; i <= lookup+1; i++ ) printHex(gpos[i]);
    System.out.print('\n');
    int count = (gpos[lookup] << 8 | gpos[lookup+1]);
    int tab = lookup + 2;
    int[] LookupList = new int[count];
    for ( j = 0; j < count; j++ ) {
        System.out.print("lookup[" + j + "] =         ");
        printHex(gpos[tab]);
        printHex(gpos[tab + 1]);
        System.out.println("        (" + ( LookupList[j] = (gpos[tab] << 8 | gpos[tab+1]) ) + ")" );
        tab += 2;
    }
    int item, sub, size;
    for ( j = 0; j < count; j++ ) {
        item = lookup + LookupList[j];
        System.out.println("Lookup [" + j + "]");
        System.out.println("Lookup Type:        " + (gpos[item] << 8 | gpos[item + 1]) );
        System.out.print("Lookup flag:        ");
        printHex(gpos[item + 2]);
        printHex(gpos[item + 3]);
        size = (gpos[item + 4] << 8 | gpos[item + 5]);
        System.out.println("\nNumber of subtables:    "  + size);
        sub = item + 6;
        int[] subTable = new int[size];
        System.out.println("Subtable offsets");
        for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
            subTable[i] = (gpos[sub] << 8 | gpos[sub +1 ]);
            sub += 2;
            System.out.println( "    " + subTable[i] );
        }
        for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
            System.out.println("Subtable [" + i + "]");
            sub = item + subTable[i];
            printSubtable(sub);
        }
    }
}

void printSubtable(int sub) {
    int format = gpos[sub] << 8 | gpos[sub + 1];
    System.out.println("Format:        " + format );
    if (format == 1) {
        /* TODO format 1*/
        return;
    }
    /* TODO format 2*/
}
```

This problem is also related to the question *[How to use kerning pairs extracted from a TTF file to correctly show glyphs as Path2D in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761064/how-to-use-kerning-pairs-extracted-from-a-ttf-file-to-correctly-show-glyphs-as-p/64777046)*.

The context is the same, but since [Apache FOP](https://github.com/jaredrummler/TrueTypeParser) doesn't read Opentype fonts and that Opentype fonts use only the kerning information from **GPOS** table, it is being much harder.

I am using the Microsoft Opentype reference, but it is way over the top (too vague, no drawings, no example code, and not enough examples). What could be more hints, some drawings, code snippets, more examples (***especially for extracting kerning tables from **GPOS** table***)?

How can I make 100% sure this code is really doing what it is supposed to do?

Comment: While it might look way over the top, GPOS processsing (rather than the ancient `kern` table process) _is incredibly hard_ because langauges are incredibly hard: GPOS is script, langsys, and feature dependent, and may require multiple passes of various GPOS lookups in specific orders to perform correct shaping. Your best bet is to just look at parser code that others have already written (Harfbuzz, Opentype.js, etc). However, it's also wise to post in the right place: https://typedrawers.com is by far the better forum to ask about font engineering =)

Comment: Hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans! I am in Graphics since the end of the 80's.  Your Primer on Bezier Curve is a fantastic job! Congrats!
I don't find languages hard. It's the documentation for Truetype and Opentype (especially the second) that are terrible. 
I understand you are a JS guy, but that's a language that I just hate. Harfbuss is in C++, which I have programmed for many years, but code in C++ is not particularly clear unless it is well commented. Thanks for the suggestion of typedrawers.com. I will definitely check it out. I had no idea it existed. Not doing fonts seriously for too long.

Comment: I have no beef with people who hate JS, it works on the web, but the web is just the web (even if it has a deep reach). Harfbuzz is basically the authority when it comes to parsing, and Behdad did a hell of a job on it, but if its source is not enough, most of the OG font folks are on typedrawers, so if you want advice from the people who literally write the OT spec: that's the place to be =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I downloaded [Opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js) and [font-inspector.html](https://opentype.js.org/font-inspector.html). I am running it with font-inspector.html locally. I also copied the site.css for formatting. I modified inspector.html to show the GPOS table. It works, but it is strange. I have to load the file using the button. It is unable to load the file I supply in the code. That's why I hate this language, :-)))

Comment: That is a super weird to say though, because that has nothing to do with javascript, and everything to do with "how that html file was written". Anyone with some JS knowledge could update that file so that you don't need to load the file using that "browse" button. That's a bit like saying you hate C# because you don't like how some kid's CLI utility needs you to pass runtime flags in all caps: that has nothing to do with C# itself =) (Modern JS does not need HTML to run, ever since Node got released years ago, it's a scripting language like php, python, etc, that can also run in the browser)

Comment: If you don't know JS, because you decided you hate it, then it's not too much of a surprise that modifications you tried to make to it don't work: but then again that's what SO is also for: "I'm a java programmer trying to change a small JS script so that it'll load my file but I can't seem to make it work" is a reasonable post. If you're using an HTML page then yeah, the browser doesn't have blanket filesystem access, only blanket _www_ access so any files you want to load need to be accessible via an http(s) url. For your work though why use a browser? Use Node instead for normal programming

Comment: You are right. I also hate C#, :-)))))). I am actually a Java Windows/Android, C++, graphics (OpenGL, PostScript, etc.) as well as parallel processing programmer. I see the convenience of Javascript, of course I do. What I hate are all those side effects and the fact that you don't have any idea where the errors are since it never crashes. It seems one can use Visual Studio to do Javascript. It would be a lot better. Oh yes, I am totally ignorant of Javascript, I admit it. I use a browser for the reasons I have already described. The programs I downloaded are on the web. I don't mind.

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea what Node is, :-))))) You won't believe. I am now an expert in **Opentype.js** now! Excellent package! Weird  interface, but extremely inclusive and high level. It was a pleasure to work with it. I should have tried it before. I didn't just because of the language. I was wrong. Excellent hint you gave me. Thanks again. My stuff is working great. I have put an extra button to generate my Java class on site. The program re-writes the html with the Java code that I just copy and paste to my Java system. It works great!

Comment: [Node](https://nodejs.org) is to JS what Python is to python: a normal interpreter installed and invoked just like `javac` and `java`, that you run on the CLI when you want to run JS. Not "browser code", but JS. With a normal, standard library for system access, file IO, networking, etc. etc. just like C, Python, Java, etc. have a standard library. If you want to just write modern JS, which has been a general purpose programming language for the better part of a decade now, you run it just like anything you run in a console/terminal. What you're doing shouldn't need a browser.

Comment: But it's good that opentype.js allowed to you solve your problem - remember to write up an answer (with code) if you think it'll help future visitors. If not, probably a good time to delete the question again.

Comment: I don't use CLI at all! Actually, I dislike and always avoided CLI. I use IDEs, instead. You won't believe the one I like most! **AIDE** in Android! For me, that's the best. Second place in my opinion is **Visual Studio**. **Eclipse** comes in third place, which is what I use for Java. I generate my JARs and I have set Windows to allow to double click the JAR to run the JAR in the JVM. I don't use `java`, neither `javac` (at least explicitly), neither Maven, etc. Better part of the decade? I spent the past 7 years brewing beer professionally. I never totally stopped programming, though.

Comment: I have added a **PS** with the solution and I also have shown an image with the result. The Javascript code is quite complex to post here, but I don't feel it is appropriate to delete the question, because it will definitely help people to not go the wrong way as I did. Obviously, **Opentype.js** is the best solution. One just needs to move to Javascript to generate Java data structures to use the font information in Java. But I can put more hints. By the way, there isn't a way to increase my *"reputation"* to allow me to use chat? Our comments are becoming too long.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem solved!**

An advice: if you are trying to do this in Java you are losing your time. This problem was solved simply using [**Opentype.js**](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js) and the site https://opentype.js.org, but particularly [**glyph inspector**](https://opentype.js.org/glyph-inspector.html) and [**font inspector**](https://opentype.js.org/font-inspector.html).

I downloaded both code by copying and pasting from **page source**. I then modified [**glyph inspector**](https://opentype.js.org/glyph-inspector.html) to do the job. You need to go deeply into **Opentype.js** to get the kerning pairs, though, but it is all there (check code below).

I ended up porting the entire program to JavaScript. I didn't program JavaScript too much before. Therefore, it must be extremely easy for whom already programs in JavaScript. This program just generates a Java class with the glyphs, the kerning pairs and widths (the *advanceWidth* for each glyph).

Here, an image to show the result:

[image]

The code below in JavaScript dumps the GPOS kerning table into the string `text`, presenting a list of sets containing the second character and the kern value in each line, while the first character of the pair appears as a Java character at the beginning of the line. Notice, that glyph indexes are avoided by using the ASCII codes of the characters.

This only dumps `' '`(space) to `'}'`, which is what is useful for English language. To expand to other characters just use Unicode.

```
<!-- indoc: true -> writes in HTML on this page  -->
const indoc = true;
const nl = (indoc) ? "<br>" : "\n";
var chars = font.tables.cmap.glyphIndexMap;
var g1,g2;
var i, j, kern;
var text = "";
for ( i = 32; i < 126; i++ ) {
    g1 = font.glyphs.get(chars[i]);
    text += "'" +
    (( i == 39 || i == 92) ? "\\" + String.fromCharCode(i) : String.fromCharCode(i) )+ "'";
    for ( j = 32; j < 126; j++ ) {
        g2 = font.glyphs.get(chars[j]);
        if ( (kern = font.getKerningValue(g1,g2)) !== 0 ) {
            text += ", { '" +
            (( j == 39 || j == 92) ? "\\" + String.fromCharCode(j) : String.fromCharCode(j) )+
            "', " + kern + " }";
        }
    }
    text += nl;
}
```

Comment: but how to calculate a relative value of move for each glyph pair? I mean, how many pixels left should I move a char to get proper visual result. Should I consider a glyph size?